# Comparison of Linq to SQL and Stored procedures in terms of performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I am using SQL Server 2005 database and my application is in ASP.NET MVC4.
The application's business logic is bit complex, containing multiple table joins and search conditions. In extreme conditions I need to join around 10 tables to fetch the data required for a single grid.
 I would like to know whether I should use SPs or Linq to SQL application code to maximize my application performance.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server basically goes through these steps to execute **any** query (stored procedure call or ad-hoc SQL statement):

1. syntactically check the query
2. if it's okay - it checks the plan cache to see if it already has an execution plan for that query
3. if there is an execution plan - that plan is (re-)used and the query executed
4. if there is no plan yet, an execution plan is determined
5. that plan is stored into the plan cache for later reuse
6. the query is executed

The point is: ad-hoc SQL and stored procedures are treated **no differently**.

If an ad-hoc SQL query is properly using **parameters** - as it should anyway, to prevent SQL injection attacks - its performance characteristics are **no different** and most definitely **no worse** than executing a stored procedure.

Stored procedure have other benefits (no need to grant users direct table access, for instance), but in terms of performance, using properly parametrized ad-hoc SQL queries is **just as efficient** as using stored procedures.

**Update:** using stored procedures over **non-parametrized** queries is better for two main reasons:

- since each non-parametrized query is a **new, different** query to SQL Server, it has to go through all the steps of determining the execution plan, for each query (thus wasting time - and also wasting plan cache space, since storing the execution plan into plan cache doesn't really help in the end, since that particular query will probably **not** be executed again)
- non-parametrized queries are at risk of SQL injection attack and should be avoided at all costs

Comment: +1 for great summary. If you anticipate many linq queries with different parameters and you have SQL2k8 or higher, consider optimizing your server for ad-hoc workloads (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645587.aspx).

Comment: You forgot the parameter sniffing step between 1 & 2. Also note that the ad-hoc query must be exactly the same, including parameter names and sizes, to be found in the cache. `.AddWithValue` on varchar parameters will rarly use the cache.

Comment: @adrianm: yes, good points - and totally agree, the ad-hoc query has to be exactly the same - down to every space and comma and semicolon - not just "similar" ....

Answer (score 0):

You are typically going to find faster performance with stored procedures because the stored procedures will re-use execution plans when possible. Linq queries essentially become ad-hoc queries against the database that without caching are processed as a new request each time.

Comment: Any properly designed and parametrized "ad-hoc" SQL query will use **exactly** the same re-using of execution plans - there's absolutely **no performance benefit** from using stored procedures! (that's a really long-standing myth - but it's nothing but a myth, it's not real!) And no: stored procedure ***ARE NOT*** pre-compiled - they go through **exactly the same** process as any ad-hoc query when first executed .....

Comment: Completely correct if you assume the cache hit rate is identical, which depends on how your server is optimized for ad-hoc workloads or not (by default).

Comment: Also, by having lots of separate Linq queries, you can easily generate lots of single-use execution plans that wastes space in the cache again unless your server is optimized for ad-hoc workloads.

Comment: yes, agreed, you might end up with a lot of smaller queries - but the perf statistics of any given ad-hoc query is no worse than a stored procedure that does the same, that's my main point. Stored procedures are very useful for certain things - but the perceived performance benefit (*pre-compiled*) is just a myth....